# How do I clone my git reposity to a remote machine?

Tags: git

I have a git repo set up on my computer. I also have a remote machine that I can ssh into. I want to clone the repo to the remote machine (and then keep them in sync with push and pull). How do I do this? I've only ever cloned from GitHub.

Comment: Can you access your computer from the remote machine (so first `ssh` to the remote, then `ssh` back to your computer)?

Comment: Well no, that's the problem (I think), I don't know my machine's address. When I type in `hostname`, I just get `username.local`, which I can't use.

Comment: Use `ifconfig` to find your IP

Answer (score 3):

1) Initialize `bare` git repository on remote machine.

```
ssh remote_machine
mkdir my_project
cd my_project
git init --bare
git update-server-info # If planning to serve via HTTP
```

2) Configure local repo to be able to pull/push from remote one.

```
git remote add origin git@remote_machine:my_project.git
git push -u origin master
```

Now both machine are in sync.

Comment: Why not just `git clone` as the first step?

Comment: This is one of the ways to do it

Comment: I tried this but got an error that the remote origin already exists. I think this is because I originally cloned the repository from a remote machine?

Comment: Probably. Just add remote machine under other name. 

`git remote add upstream git@remote_machine:my_project.git`
`git push -u upstream master`

Comment: doesn't work. "my_project" will have git files in it where as local machine will have those files in a ".git" folder. then I try `cd my_project; git init --bare .git`. Now I get the git files where I expected them. So I follow your part 2 steps. Then I go to remote and type `git status` and I get `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`